# How to use "Multi-Paint" while weight painting?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, vertex-groups

I noticed there is an option allowing one to paint on multiple bones together:

[image]

The [document](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/weight_paint/tool_settings/options.html) says:

> Paint on all selected vertex groups simultaneously, in a way that
> preserves their relative influence. This can be useful when tweaking
> weights in an area that is affected by more than three bones at once,
> e.g. certain areas on a character’s face.

But how can I select more than one vertex groups? `Ctrl+LMB` selects only one bone. `Ctrl+Shift+LMB` on a bone doesn't work. The mesh properties panel lists all the vertex groups, but I can only select one there as well.

Comment: Don't hold CTRL when you're selecting additional bones, just Shift+LMB (in 2.9x)

Comment: @MartyFouts Lol now I feel dumb. Thank you!