# Asking about Weight Painting & Easy Weight add-on

Tags: weight-painting, weight-paint-mode

guys. I am a newbie when coming to **Weight Painting**. I am using the **Easy Weight add-on** because I heard it's much better. But I have some questions:

[image]

1. What is **Accumulate** and How to use it?
2. I usually combine **Front Faces & Projected** to paint through the model. Is there another use for these features?
3. What is **Clean Weights**?
4. What is **Multi-Paint**?
5. At Operators: there is **Normalize Deform, Clean, Wipe Empty & Wipe Unused**, and I know nothing about these ? Do I need to know all for Weight Painting game characters?

Do you guys have any tips for less annoying Painting? For example: I know about Weight (top right menu) --> **Smooth Paint**. It really helps a lot.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: That appears to be a Blender Studio addon and not built into Blender so I doubt many here will have heard of it. The documentation for it is [here](https://studio.blender.org/pipeline/addons/easy_weights).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But I use this add-on to ask because I think it lists all the most important up of Weight Painting, such as Accumulate and Multi-Paint. These are the main things I want to ask

Comment: Any answers are likely to be opinion-based and off-topic here. If you want to ask about how to use a single option that's fine, but don't ask about more than one in a question and search for previous answers first. For example: Multi-Paint shows up here;  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/239479/how-to-use-multi-paint-while-weight-painting.